# Why is C++ "this" poorly designed?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, this

1. For every `a` and `b` which are non-const pointers of the same type, you can do `a = b;`, right?
2. Inside non-const member functions the `this` keyword exists, which is a non-const pointer. So logicaly if `b` is same type as `this` you can also do `this = b;` right?

Wrong.

You cannot do `this = b;`, because `this` uses pointer syntax but logically `this` is a reference!

But why on earth is `this` syntactically a pointer but logically reference?

Can this weird behavior be corrected in the next C++ standard, by introducing a new keyword, for example `me` which will be a reference not only logically but also syntactically?

(See also my attempt to solve this here: "*[Is it a good idea to "#define me (*this)"?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/249767/is-it-a-good-idea-to-define-me-this)*")

Comment: C++ is quite well designed by quite expert people. It has the (ugly but practical) requirement of being (reasonably) C compatible.

Comment: [`this` predates references.](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#this). That's why it's a pointer.

Comment: why do you say it's "logically a reference" when it's a const pointer? 
(Not the same as pointer-to-const)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`this` is (like `nullptr`)  a **constant pointer**; the pointed data is `const` if and only if `this` appears in the body of a `const` member function.

<sup>You cannot change a constant pointer, like you cannot change a constant literal like `23`.</sup>

So assignment to `this` like

```
this = p;  // WRONG
```

is prohibited for the same reasons assignment to `nullptr` is forbidden:

```
nullptr = 0; // wrong
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right, good explanation. I am also confusing pointers to const data with const pointers to data.

Comment: Hmpf. `nullptr` is not a *pointer*, and thus not a *constant pointer*, but it is a *null pointer constant*. Just like `0`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is NOT poorly designed. You almost never have local variables with the same names as class member names. While this construction does occur in constructors for POD or nearly POD objects, the language has a better way of dealing with this. Behold:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
    public:
        A(int m1, int m2) : m1(m1), m2(m2) {}
        int m1;
        int m2;
};

int main()
{
    A a(1, 2);
    printf("%d, %d\n", a.m1, a.m2);
}
```

I'm sure we can agree this demonstration is full of horrors, but the point is obvious. The constructor has local variables with the same name as members and initializes the members with the same names as local variables. You can run this program and get the output "1, 2".

Also, in C++ we expect that we may declare functions having good parameter names (for hinting) and bad names for the actual implementation. This can even be done for inline functions if we bother to declare them separately rather than bodily in the class definition.

For all of these reasons, a member function rarely needs to access its class explicitly but only its pointer, thus the `this` keyword is a pointer.

Historical artifact: `this` was once not `const` and could be assigned to. This was a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

One can make an argument that `this` is a bit clumsy.
Having a `self`-reference instead would probably feel a bit more natural nowadays:
Its type could then carry slightly more information in it than the type of `this` can, namely:

1. Whether the member-function was guaranteed called on an rvalue-reference, and
2. that it actually always refers to an object.

Still, when C++ finally got references (invented for operator-overloading, I think), the decision on `this` was already ancient history. And backwards-compatibility is no laughing matter.